# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: angular, angular-material

While running angular 17 on local getting this error ./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import. @import '../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming';

How to import it properly or there is other way to import ?

Comment: Look here: https://v8.material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Specifically, this text;
'If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your styles.css file:'

@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Try to replace your current import in styles with that?